# AWS Route53: Redirecting Domain without Changing URL in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53

I have a Domain bought from AWS and Hosted on AWS Route 53. Assume the domain is `example.com`. Moreover, I have an account on zendesk with a subdomain `example.zendesk.com`.

What I would like to do is to map a subdomain `help.example.com` to `example.zendesk.com`. I am able to do so by adding a CNAME record in Route53. When I write `help.example.com` in my browser, it does redirect to the requested page. However, the domain the browser changes to `example.zendesk.com`. I would like to be able to get redirected to the page without the domain being changed in the browser.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, unless you point the domain to the server directly. Otherwise, it would be a redirect and there is nothing you can do about it. If you really need to do this, you would need a nginx instance to handle the redirect, since you can rewrite the domain.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a way of doing this using iframe, put this html on S3 and map your help.example.com to S3 static website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My website</title>
    <base target="iframe">
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px">
    <iframe id="iframe" src="example.zendesk.com" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; border:0px">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Other option is rewrite rule but I don't know if AWS support it or not

Comment: This is very clever.